# Test a server connection?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I have online payments that sends data to a server (Authorize.Net). If the server is down, for example, I get a generic error page from Authorize.Net. Instead, I'd like to test to see if the server is available and working first. If so, then send along the payment info. If it doesn't work, then redirect to an error page.

My issue is that I have not the slightest idea of how to reach a server to test if it is sending a response back or not. Can someone point me in the right direction of what I can use to grab a response from the server? I am using asp.net and VB if that matters.

Comment: @DavidBS Probably? I don't really know what options I have anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a PING to see ONLY if the server is reachable:

```
      Dim Server4PING As String = "www.server.com"
       ' do not use HTTP or any / in the name - just the name itself

      Dim ResultPings As String = ""
      Using p As Ping = New Ping
           ResultPings = p.Send(Server4Ping, 5000).RoundtripTime.ToString
      End Using

      ' In this sample, I set timeout value to 5 seconds.
      ' ResultPing will return the time to reach server or the error.
```

I wish you good luck.

PS: more info about it?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2):

PING is good, but the info you get is limited to whether or not the server is talking on the network or not at the transport (IP) level.  Another option would be to send an HTTP `OPTIONS` or `HEAD` request.  This would let you know whether or not there is an HTTP server answering requests at the application level.  If you're really concerned you could do both.